# How to download data from google account when you run out of space?

Tags: backup, sync, gmail, google-drive, google-photos

I run out of space on google (used 14.5GB of 15GB). This means like 9GB of photos and 5 GB of email attachments. I want to download everything and then clean the cloud. I realized google does not really provide any tool useful for this purpose.

I tried:

1. [Google Takeout](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en) - problem is that this creates bunch of large .zip files stored in Google Drive. But I don't have any space left in my google drive => I cannot use it.
2. [Google Drive Desktop](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) (no linux version, so I downloaded the windows one). It tells to synchronize with google photos. The problem is it synchronize only one-way (from desktop to cloud). I did not find any way how to use it do download photos from cloud to desktop. I can create local (desktop) mirror of google drive (like google docs etc.) but this is only 100MB of data. I cannot use it to make local mirror of neither google photos (9GB) nor emails (5GB) ... so it is again useless for me
3. [gphotos-sync](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Local_incremental_Google_Photos_backup_on_Ubuntu.html) - The problem is it needs some OAuth authorization which requres to have google-cloud account which is not for free
4. [Imagenes](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-google-photos-on-linux-desktop/) - it provides desktop GUI equivalent to web version google photos. I don't see any option to download/sychronize/backup photos from cloud to desktop...

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE:** Sorry, it turned out the 1st option [Google Takeout](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en) works just fine. It tried to upload the .zip finel to Google-Drive which failed due to insufficient space, but it is still possible to download through Google Takeout interface. The Photos are nicely organized in folders for each Album, so it is rather convenient. I'm sorry this was probably my mistake.

Comment: You can download and manage everything from the web.

Comment: Google Cloud accounts *are* free – specific resources (hosting) cost money, but registering an API project doesn't.

Comment: You should post the "update" as answer and accept it or delete this question so it no longer shows as unanswered.